# can't install grunt-combine-media-queries on Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

I need help. I trying install grunt-combine-media-queries:

```
npm install grunt-combine-media-queries --save
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.17
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-combine-media-queries" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! path /var/www/dev/htmlacademy/education.htmlacademy/less/test_area_less/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/sshpk/bin/sshpk-conv
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/var/www/dev/htmlacademy/education.htmlacademy/less/test_area_less/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/sshpk/bin/sshpk-conv'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/var/www/dev/htmlacademy/education.htmlacademy/less/test_area_less/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/sshpk/bin/sshpk-conv'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Is there any solution for this? Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install utilizing the [--no-bin-links](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#bin-links) flag. For example:

`$ npm install grunt-combine-media-queries --save --no-bin-links`

A quote from the docs reads:

> Set to false to have it not do this. This can be used to work around the fact that some file systems don't support symlinks, even on ostensibly Unix systems..